# 2D Array Query - unexpected commas in output despite using join();

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I'm doing my best to learn jQuery, and I'm a little stuck. I'm trying to make a 2d array of form data in a table, and it seems to work, but I'm returning commas when I try to get the values, even when I use join().

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. I'm using a button event to trigger an alert to show the values with join().

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="table order-list">
  <thead>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <tr data-key="1">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="D"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="E"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="F"></td>
  </tr>

   <tr data-key="2">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="H"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="I"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="J"></td>

    </tr>


       <tr data-key="2">
    <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="K"></td>
     <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="L"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="M"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<button id="btn1" style="width:100px, height:100px">Click</button>
```

Here is the jquery/javascript:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){

  var tableData = $('tr').map(function() {
  return [$(this).find(':input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val()
  }).get()]
  }).get()

  alert(tableData.join(""));

console.log(tableData)  
});
```

This is my output for the above: D,E,FH,I,JK,L,M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from the question that your goal is to remove *all* the commas in the output string then you need to also `join()` the inner array too. Also note that you can make the code more succinct using arrow functions. Try this:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  var tableData = $('tr').map((_, tr) => [
    $(tr).find(':input').map((_, inp) => inp.value).get().join('')
  ]).get();
  console.log(tableData.join(''));
});
```

```css
#btn1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table order-list">
  <thead>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-key="1">
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="D"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="E"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="F"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key="2">
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="H"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="I"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="J"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key="2">
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="K"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="L"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="M"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="btn1">Click</button>
```

However, if your goal is to create that output then you don't need two loops. You can loop directly through the inputs to create the flattened string:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  var tableData = $('input.form-control').map((_, inp) => inp.value).get().join('');
  console.log(tableData);
});
```

```css
#btn1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table order-list">
  <thead>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-key="1">
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="D"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="E"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="F"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key="2">
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="H"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="I"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="J"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-key="2">
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="K"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="L"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control" name="" value="M"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="btn1">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory! That works perfectly. Ultimately I want to use php to take this array and store it in SQL, is it your opinion that using a 2d array like this is suitable, or do I need to use something like a json?

Comment: I'd definitely use JSON for that, then you can keep the 2D structure of the data intact, although whether that's important or not depends on what you use it for.

Comment: I've been having a look at this, and I notice that every data element has a reference by which it's identified, so when I  use JSON stringify on the above, it returns this: [[],["D","E","F"],["H","I","J"],["K","L","M"]] . I'm not sure that's right. Do you know what the correct procedure would be? (sorry for all the questions!)

Comment: That looks right to me. Do you mean that you're trying to remove the first empty `[]`?

Comment: I think it was more that the example jsons I see use a name to identify each item. I stole some other code and managed to produce an array of objects in this format. Do you know how I might access the individual variables in this, tableData[1][1] doesn't seem to work on this one:
key: key: 1
values: (3) […]​​
0: "D"
1: "E"​​
2: "F"
length: 3
values: Array(3) [ "D", "E", "F" ]
<prototype>: {…

Comment: That's the same as your original, bar the first empty element I mentioned (ie. the `[]`). Note that JSON is a way of serialising objects and arrays. The ones you've seen with 'names to identify them' are objects. Yours is a nested arrays, and arrays do not have those names, also known as 'properties'. The result in either case is still a JSON string.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the above, there are some crumbs under my 'v' key!

Comment: Done! Thanks to you Rory, I'll do that after some more figuring on it!